# Reading multiple .csv files into Matlab while organizing them into new matrices

Tags: matlab, csv, file-io, import-from-csv

I have lots of .csv files that I want to read into MATLAB, but doing some organization along the way

My first problem is my data looks like this:

```
[...

file1  
ex1  
6;0  
8;0  
9;1  
file1  
ex2  
7;0  
8;1  
3;2  
file1  
ex3  
7;0  
8;1  
3;2
```

The import wizard on MATLAB for some reason only takes the first header text then the data set below that and throws away everything when it reaches the next text header. So how can I organize the file so that it looks like this instead?

```
[...

file1......file1.....file1  
ex1.......ex2.......ex3  
6;0.......7;0.......7;0  
8;0.......8;1.......8;1  
9;1.......3;2.......3;2
```

NOTE: the number of rows for the different ex's is always different, so you can't just spilt the file into regular chunks.

My second problem is then to compare the same experiments from different files. So I want to take the columns below "ex1" from all the different files and line then up horizontally against each other in a new matrix. So that it looks like this:

```
file1.....file2.....file3.....    
ex1.......ex1.......ex1.......    
6;0.......6;0.......6;0.......  
8;0.......8;0.......8;0.......  
9;1.......9;1.......9;1.......
```

NOTE: the ex's in the different files are in different orders. I need to match up ex's within files based on matching one of the lines of header (e.g. whenever it is called 'track1').

---

#### EDIT:

This is how the [actual data](http://pastebin.com/ZmSsJ3Pc) looks like.

Comment: to be exact, these are not comma separated files, rather text files with custom format...

Comment: I receive them with the .csv extension, but when opened in excel or wordpad they automatically split into 1 long column.

Comment: could you upload the example of file with few lines?

Comment: What do the semicolons mean?  You can't have semicolons in a numeric matlab matrix.

Comment: the semicolons are dividing the x and y axis of the numeric data. If they can be split at the same time, that would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of rows in each ex is different, you must use a cell matrix.

```
file = 'file1.csv';
h = 2; % # header lines
num_ex = 3;
r = h; % track the current row in the file
data = cell(1,num_ex);
for i=1:num_ex
    s = importdata(file, ';', r);
    x = s.data;
    data{i} = x;
    r = r + size(x,1) + h;
end
```

Then you can access your data using the curly bracket cell matrix notation

```
ex = 2;
x = data{ex};
```

So you get

```
x = [ 7  0
      8  1
      3  2 ]
```

For your second problem, you can add a loop to go through each file

```
filenames = {'file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv'};
h = 2; % # header lines
num_ex = 3;
r = h; % track the current row in the file
data = cell(1,num_ex);
for i=1:num_ex
    for f=1:length(filenames)
        file = filenames{f};
        s = importdata(file, ';', r);
        x = s.data;
        data{i} = [data{i} x];
    end
    r = r + size(x,1) + h;
end
```

So that `data{1}` has all the data for ex 1, etc.

Comment: How does your current code skip the first two header lines? My understanding was that the first line in file1.csv is actually `file1'...

Comment: The third parameter to `dlmread` tells how many header lines (rows) to skip.

Comment: Hm, I don't see what the problem is, but when I try your solution I get "??? Error using ==> dlmread at 145
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 4, field 1) ==> file1\n"

Comment: hi there. I've tried the script but am getting an error message: ??? Error using ==> dlmread at 145  
Mismatch between file and format string.  
Trouble reading number from file (row 88, field 1) ==> agmm\n  

Error in ==> readfiles at 7  
    x = dlmread(file, ';', r, 0);    In this case "agmm" is the first header (there are 4 in total) and there are 87 lines of numeric data before "agmm" is repeated again (it is the participant code)

Comment: Ah, I see Jonas found the same problem. It's like when using the import wizard, Matlab doesn't like the repeating headers.

Comment: Sorry, using `importdata` instead of `dlmread` will work without choking on the non-numeric data.  Updated answer.

Comment: Hi Kristi. I think your solution should work. However I have another problem with my data, which is that in different files the ex's are in different orders. So I need the script to read the headers and match up the same ex's between files. You can tell which ex it is by the 2nd header line (not the first).

Comment: Alternatively, is there a way to re-order the ex's according to a list that I specify (of the 2nd header lines)?

Answer (score 1):

While I recognise this is not a full solution to your problem, an alternate solution I often use to overcome text editing (and the horrific speed penalty you get when parsing in MATLAB) is to load your data in through the MATLAB connectors to Java or C#.

It's fairly easy to call C# and Java from MATLAB, and I do a lot of my text stuff that was.